# Determine steady state in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have sets of data which when plotted look like this:
[image: Force vs Time]

How can  determine the "avarage" value these 3 data sets flatten out on? In other words, the average "steady state" of these three data sets.

By eyeballing it I can estimate that the average steady state is `4.5N` but I'm hoping that there is a nice matlab toolbox (I have them all installed) or another method.

Note: This is Force vs Time.

Comment: I Personally would never called "steady state" what you have. the `N`s are still not steady there, their derivative over time is still changing (It looks like its negative). On eof the methods could be commputing the average `dN/dt` in fixed time intervals, and if that goes to zero, helps to detect steady states. However, in your case that wont happen because its not zero

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes I figured it's not really steady state. But I didn't know the correct term for it. Perhaps I can fit the graph?